# Hive timestamp function issue

Tags: apache-spark, hive, timestamp

Hour gets incremented by 1 hour automatically for few random date time on conversion.

[image: problem screenshot]

This is not happening for other hours of the day and the same hour(02) in next day. This issue occurs for random date and timestamp.

similar issue happens to 2022-03-13 02:57:54

Thanks

Solution for the above problem

Comment: The issue is not clear! please explain more with a minimal producible example input and output

Comment: The Hour HH in the screen shot SQL has 02. whereas in the output its changed to 03. We receive files and when we insert into hive table. in some random date time, the hour gets incremented by 1 hour. its not happening for all the records. but few rows are impacted by this issue.

Comment: It seems a timezone issue between the worker machines, could you try to set `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')` and try again?

Comment: It works. Thank you. Do you know the equivalent config for hive?

Comment: Great, added it as an answer!

Comment: Do you know the equivalent config for hive?

Comment: Hive depends on the JVM timezone, so you need to make sure to set something like `SET mapred.child.java.opts= -Duser.timezone=UTC` before inserting data

Answer (score 0):

It seems a timezone issue between workers machines, you need to set the timezone as a property

```py
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
```